# HTML Button and AMPSCRIPT in LandingPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an HTML & CSS Landing Page where my goal is when the customer click on the button: he will populate a Data Extension and new window will open in the same tab:

```
<button class="button button2" style="float:right" 
name="unsub" type="hidden" value="true">Unsubscribe</button>
```

The AMPscript:

```
%%[
IF NOT EMPTY(RequestParameter("unsub")) THEN
SET @SubKey = RequestParameter("subkey")
SET @email = RequestParameter("E-mail")
UpsertData('Unsub_Customers',1,'SubKey',@subkey,'E-mail',@email)
ENDIF
]%%
```

The problem is that when i tried to put the *HTML form action* the link open, but the Data Extension not populate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope your AMPscript part is correct...And only have trouble in HTML section. As I dont see full code, I have tried to simulate the demo, and the below worked fine. Please try to compare with the below and figure out.

```ampscript
%%[
IF NOT EMPTY(RequestParameter("unsub")) THEN
SET @SubKey = RequestParameter("subkey")
SET @email = RequestParameter("email")
UpsertData('2019DEC21_Demo',1,'SubKey',@subkey,'E-mail',@email) //change your DE Name
Redirect(concat("https://salesforce.stackexchange.com?subkey=", @SubKey))
ENDIF
]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>SFMC-Ninja.tech</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:maroon; text-align:center;">SF-StackExchange Demo</h1>

<form id="myform" action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post" target="_blank">
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email">
<label>SubKey</label>
<input type="text" name="subkey">
<input name="unsub" type="hidden" value="true"/>
<input type="submit" value="Unsubscribe"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And I also verified it Upsert the DE.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Vishal. But when do you click in your button whant happens? I think i'm not clear, i want that when you click in the button, another page opens (url) and DE be populated

Comment: As of now the above code updates the Data Extension and stays in same page... If you wish you can redirect it once submitted... If you provide the URL I can demonstrate... Hope I'm clear.

Comment: For my if you could help me kindly you can use the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @JoaoMarano I have updated the code, please check...FYI I have added below code...... **target="_blank** and ````Redirect(concat("https://salesforce.stackexchange.com?subkey=", @SubKey))````